# Spark on Kubernetes - org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Created a **Spark on Kubernetes cluster** with **kubeadm**. And trying to run a spark example results in the below error in driver pod:

```
2024-02-28T12:07:42,256 ERROR [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
```

The **driver pod** seems to timeout (15 seconds) requesting executor pods (via kube-apiserver):

```
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:520) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.AsyncUtils.lambda$withTimeout$0(AsyncUtils.java:42) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.7.2.jar:?]
```

The **kube-apiserver** logs only one entry when the job/driver pod is shuttig down:

```
12:07:43.690591       1 trace.go:236] Trace[1366723152]: "Get" accept:application/json, */*,audit-id:715d28ee-4a16-4c84-b2aa-1d65296fd877,client:82.20.143.238,protocol:HTTP/2.0,resource:pods,scope:resource,url:/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/java-spark-pi-stackable-driver/log,user-agent:kubectl/v1.28.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/855e7c4,verb:CONNECT (28-Feb-2024 12:07:24.747) (total time: 18943ms):
Trace[1366723152]: ---"Writing http response done" 18940ms (12:07:43.690)
Trace[1366723152]: [18.943273188s] [18.943273188s] END
```

All the posts I see about this **KubernetesClientException** has a clear error message but not in my case. So it is not clear to me if the driver pod has problem seeing the api-server or the api-server taking too long to respond. Is there anything else I should look in to?

`Kubernetes Setup`:

```
- Kubernetes cluster created with kubeadm
- Deployed calico pod network with the default cidr 10.244.0.0/16
- Deployed Spark operator from Stackable

Note: I also used spark-on-k8s-operator from Google but the driver pod hangs immediately after exec command and shows no log4j logs or errors
```

`Full Driver pod log`:

```
++ id -u
+ myuid=1000
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
+ set +e
++ getent passwd 1000
+ uidentry=stackable:x:1000:1000::/stackable:/bin/bash
+ set -e
+ '[' -z stackable:x:1000:1000::/stackable:/bin/bash ']'
+ '[' -z /usr/lib/jvm/jre-11 ']'
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/stackable/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
++ command -v readarray
+ '[' readarray ']'
+ readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -z x ']'
+ export PYSPARK_PYTHON
+ '[' -z ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -z ']'
+ '[' -z x ']'
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH='/opt/spark/conf::/stackable/spark/jars/*'
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH='/opt/spark/conf::/stackable/spark/jars/*:/stackable/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3'
+ case "$1" in
+ shift 1
+ CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --conf "spark.executorEnv.SPARK_DRIVER_POD_IP=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /stackable/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=10.244.65.162 --conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_DRIVER_POD_IP=10.244.65.162 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi local:///stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar
Files local:///stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar from /stackable/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.0.jar to /stackable/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.0.jar
2024-02-28T12:07:21,071 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2024-02-28T12:07:21,841 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Running Spark version 3.5.0
2024-02-28T12:07:21,843 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - OS info Linux, 4.18.0-532.el8.x86_64, amd64
2024-02-28T12:07:21,845 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Java version 11.0.21
2024-02-28T12:07:21,954 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceUtils - ==============================================================
2024-02-28T12:07:21,956 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceUtils - No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
2024-02-28T12:07:21,957 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceUtils - ==============================================================
2024-02-28T12:07:21,958 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Submitted application: Spark Pi
2024-02-28T12:07:22,050 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceProfile - Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 640, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
2024-02-28T12:07:22,075 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceProfile - Limiting resource is cpus at 1 tasks per executor
2024-02-28T12:07:22,078 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.resource.ResourceProfileManager - Added ResourceProfile id: 0
2024-02-28T12:07:22,237 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager - Changing view acls to: stackable
2024-02-28T12:07:22,238 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager - Changing modify acls to: stackable
2024-02-28T12:07:22,240 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager - Changing view acls groups to:
2024-02-28T12:07:22,241 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager - Changing modify acls groups to:
2024-02-28T12:07:22,242 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: stackable; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: stackable; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY
2024-02-28T12:07:23,056 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 7078.
2024-02-28T12:07:23,147 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering MapOutputTracker
2024-02-28T12:07:23,255 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering BlockManagerMaster
2024-02-28T12:07:23,353 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
2024-02-28T12:07:23,356 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
2024-02-28T12:07:23,366 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
2024-02-28T12:07:23,461 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager - Created local directory at /var/data/spark-45dd9279-d730-4760-a216-b573f67b151c/blockmgr-10fec243-0a5c-4ff5-aabc-49760a23be34
2024-02-28T12:07:23,543 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore - MemoryStore started with capacity 191.2 MiB
2024-02-28T12:07:23,576 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkEnv - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
2024-02-28T12:07:23,838 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @9144ms to org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2024-02-28T12:07:24,176 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils - Start Jetty 0.0.0.0:4040 for SparkUI
2024-02-28T12:07:24,257 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.52.v20230823; built: 2023-08-23T19:29:37.669Z; git: abdcda73818a1a2c705da276edb0bf6581e7997e; jvm 11.0.21+9-LTS
2024-02-28T12:07:24,338 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server - Started @9648ms
2024-02-28T12:07:24,400 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@40709f9{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2024-02-28T12:07:24,402 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
2024-02-28T12:07:24,474 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22bf9122{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2024-02-28T12:07:24,561 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Added JAR local:/stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar at file:/stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar with timestamp 1709122041774
2024-02-28T12:07:24,563 WARN [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - The JAR local:///stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar at file:/stackable/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar has been added already. Overwriting of added jar is not supported in the current version.
2024-02-28T12:07:24,858 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory - Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file



2024-02-28T12:07:42,256 ERROR [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3209) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:582) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189) [scala-library-2.12.18.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093) [spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:30) [spark-examples.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala) [spark-examples.jar:3.5.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.makeExecutorPodsAllocator(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:179) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:133) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3203) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:520) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:535) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:478) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:741) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.requireFromServer(BaseOperation.java:185) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:141) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:92) ~[kubernetes-client-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.$anonfun$driverPod$1(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:96) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230) ~[scala-library-2.12.18.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.<init>(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:94) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.makeExecutorPodsAllocator(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:179) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:133) ~[spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3203) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.AsyncUtils.lambda$withTimeout$0(AsyncUtils.java:42) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.lambda$schedule$6(Utils.java:473) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.7.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
2024-02-28T12:07:42,303 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.SparkContext - SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
2024-02-28T12:07:42,351 INFO [main] org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped Spark@40709f9{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2024-02-28T12:07:42,359 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI - Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-pi-stackable-d629788def9c6c02-driver-svc.default.svc:4040
2024-02-28T12:07:42,466 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-0] org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
```